# How to edit template?

Tags: html, templates, blogger

http://musicmoviesshows.blogspot.in/ is my blog and I need to make changes in the big grey box in the center (replacing it by a picture). What code should I use and where?

The code is exceptionally long and I got this template from Themexpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the navbar ("Title bar")  try to find the code that creates that and then delete the divs that you don't want. Try to rummage around the source code that Themexpose provided for you

Comment: Yes I solved the problem of title bar, but now I need to put a picture in the big grey box. What is that known as?

Comment: I used the developer tools available in my chrome browser. I found it, its called <div id="my-slider"></div>. Hope you find it.